# rtabmap+pose file

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i am following the tutorials of rtabmap and use this package for stereo vision. i created the map with stereo images from file (link:https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Stereo-mapping) for ros and saved RGBD_pose.txt file. the file's parameters is (x,y,z,qx,qy,qz,qw). but i don't know where is origin?  and what is qw?
please help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273338/rtabmap+pose-file/) by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first pose would be the origin. The qx, qy, qz, qw are the 4 quaternion values.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0